# Callback function sum a hours and minutes of a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, callback, datatables

I'm trying to sum total hours and minutes of a column of a datatable.

I've this time format in DT cells: 4h 12m

Then something like:

4h 12m
2h 8m
4h 0m

The total must be:

10h 20m

I try with something like:

```
'footerCallback': function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                                var api = this.api(), data;

                                //Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                                var numVal = function ( i ) {
                                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                                            parseFloat(i.split("€")[1].split("<")[0].replace(/,/, '.')) :
                                            typeof i === 'number' ?
                                                    i : 0;
                                };
                                var perTemp = function ( i ) {
                                    // I need some help here...
                                }

                                // Total over all pages
                                totalvar = api
                                        .column( 3 )
                                        .data()
                                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                            return numVal(a) + numVal(b);
                                        }, 0 );
                                totaltemp= api
                                        .column( 4 )
                                        .data()
                                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                            return perTemp(a) + perTemp(b);
                                        }, 0 );

                                // Update footer
                                $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html('€ ' + totalvar);
                                $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(totaltemp[0] + "h" + totaltemp[1] + "m");
```

I need some help with the "perTemp" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = ["4h 12m 2h 8m 4h 0m", "4h 12m"];
var s = a.join(","); // "4h 12m 2h 8m 4h 0m,4h 12m"
var re = /([\d]*?(h|m))/gmi;

var res = s.match(re); // Array [ "4h", "12m", "2h", "8m", "4h", "0m", "4h", "12m" ]

var hours = res.filter(function(value){
   if(value.indexOf("h") > -1){
     return true;
   }
}).map(function(value){
   return parseInt(value.substr(0, value.length-1))
}).reduce(function(pre, cur){
  return pre + cur
}); // Array [ "4h", "2h", "4h", "4h" ] -> Array [ 4, 2, 4, 4 ] -> 14

 var min = res.filter(function(value){
   if(value.indexOf("m") > -1){
     return true;
   }
}).map(function(value){
   return parseInt(value.substr(0, value.length-1))
}).reduce(function(pre, cur){
  return pre + cur
}); // 32

// add hour if > 60 min
hour += Math.floor(min/60);
min = min % 60;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've only one problem with this script.

Comment: Ex: I've (1h, 2h, 0h) and (00m, 00m, 30m) and I've as result: 3h 3m.... hours is ok, minutes no.